# ActionLink and Url.Action target different locations when area attribute is specified in Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In _LoggedInUser.cshtml (which is in Views/Shared folder at application's root) view I want to call the Logout method of AC controller. I have two options here:

Using ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "AC", new { area = string.Empty })
```

OR

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "AC", new { area = string.Empty })">Logout</a>
```

I am specifying area because I want to call action method of AC controller irrespective of area it is in.

As far as I understand the difference between @Html.ActionLink() and @Url.action is that first generates an anchor tag where as second returns a url (Please correct me if I am wrong), so I guess both should target to same location but here @Html.ActionLink has following link location:

```
http://localhost:13974/Home/logout?Length=2
```

whereas `<a href="@Url.Action(`....  has following link location:

```
http://localhost:13974/AC/Logout
```

Both links are working fine when area attribute is removed but @Html.ActionLink() breaks when I specify the area

Why both the links are targeting to different locations when I specify area?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "AC", new { area = string.Empty }, null)
```

You can use overload, [`LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

For more info visit [LinkExtensions.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Additionally,

There is no overload as `LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object)`

Answer (score 3):

What you want is this overload:

//linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "AC", new {area = string.Empty}, null) %>
```

try and let us know if this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong overload of the `ActionLink` method. Change it to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "AC", null, new { area = string.Empty })
```