# a tag not processed by razor on area with asp.net core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

Well, my problem is the following :

I am creating an application with asp.net core. I have like 20+ controllers in the first version.

I am planning to add new features. So, I decided to work with areas.

I created a folder called Areas Added inside of it another folder for an area called Administration. I moved the controllers and views to this folder.

I added the attribute Area("Administration") to all of the controllers of this area.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

I can navigate by typing the URLs.

I have two problems :

1. Razor no more process tags like

   - a asp-action="SomeAction"
   - a asp-action="SomeAction" asp-controller="SomeController"
   - a asp-action="SomeAction" asp-controller="SomeController" asp-controller="SomeArea"
2. Labels on forms no more show up (I am using standard bootstrap 3 forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the override that inludes the area part of the route. Se the link below as an example.

[ActionLink and Url.Action target different locations when area attribute is specified in Asp.net MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739206/actionlink-and-url-action-target-different-locations-when-area-attribute-is-spec)

Comment: Very helpful. Than you for your answer.